# dropwizard SaveOrUpdateEventListener

Tags: hibernate, dropwizard

I tried to have a SaveOrUpdateDateListener extends DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener in dropwizard hibernate. When I registered it within EventListenerGroup in Applicaion class as below:

```
@Override
public void run(DFConfiguration configuration,
                Environment environment) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    //register custom listener into EventListener
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = hibernate.getSessionFactory();
    EventListenerRegistry listenerRegistry = sessionFactory.getSessionFactoryOptions().getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
    EventListenerGroup<SaveOrUpdateEventListener> evlg = listenerRegistry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.SAVE_UPDATE);
    evlg.appendListener(new SaveOrUpdateDateListener());
```

}

This is the SaveOrUpdateDateListener class.
public class SaveOrUpdateDateListener extends DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener {

```
@Override
public void onSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) {
    logger.debug("Entering onSaveOrUpdate()");

    if (event.getObject() instanceof AuditableBase) {
        AuditableBase object = (AuditableBase) event.getObject();

        // set the Updated date/time
        object.setUpdated(new Date().getTime());

        // set the Created date/time
        if (object.getCreated() == 0) {
            object.setCreated(new Date().getTime());
        }
    }
}
```

}

It threw exceptions at deployment time:

Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.event.service.spi.EventListenerRegistry], Stack trace: org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.event.service.spi.EventListenerRegistry]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:126)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This is not readable. Please [format your question properly](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). I doubt you will get any answers if you leave it like that.

Comment: I just formatted my question, thanks!

Comment: The purpose of creating a custom SaveOrUpdateDateListener is to automatically add created and updated time when persist entities.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way for it. Since I dealt with createdTime and updatedTime, @CreationTimestamp and @UpdateTimestamp do the trick for me. So I don't need to have any custom listener at all. Yeah...

```
 @Column(name="createdTime", nullable = false, insertable = true,updatable = false)
 @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
 @CreationTimestamp
 private Date createdTime;

 @Column(name="updatedTime", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
 @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
 @UpdateTimestamp
 private Date updatedTime;
```